# Nvchad looking weird on mac pro m2

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I have installed nvchad configs for neovim. But the colors look so weird, nothing like the screenshots on the official website.
My os is Ventura and shell is zsh. Nerd fonts are set as given in the nvchad website
[image]

[image]